# Insert data to database table field with type decimal(12,2)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv, mariadb

I'm working on `csv` import to database, I Successfully read the `csv` file contents, and the following code will import the content to the database.

```
<?php  
foreach ($data as $value) {
  $data = array (
    'checklist_item_id' => ($this->table == 'checklist_item') ? $this->id : null,
    'imp_sequence_no'   => $value['Sequence No.'],
    'imp_vendor_tin'    => $value['Vendor TIN'],
    'imp_vendor_name'   => $value['Vendor Name'],
    'imp_input_vat_per_client' => $value['Input VAT per client'],
    'imp_gsi    '       => $value['Goods/Services/Importations']
  );
  $this->db->insert("transaction", $data);
}
?>
```

This line

```
  'imp_input_vat_per_client' => $value['Input VAT per client'],
```

of the code, has a value with a decimal point, and sometimes with comma.

for example:

```
  624.00
  312.00
  1,137.57
```

`imp_input_vat_per_client`, is a field name with a type `decimal(12,2)`.

I successfully insert the data to the database but, the value of the field `imp_input_vat_per_client` in all rows are,

```
  0.00
```

Can you give explanation what happen?
What to do with it?

Comment: thats default value for DECIMAL datatype, you're probably inserting blank values !

Comment: No, I'm sure, because when you use var_dump it show there is

Comment: i think you sending the String value to data for example you sending the value 

$value = "10,22";

Comment: you need to change your data type to varchar and check it again

Comment: Need to change imp_input_vat_per_client to text or varchar(255)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
'imp_input_vat_per_client' => $value['Input VAT per client'],
```

to

```
'imp_input_vat_per_client' => floatval(str_replace(',', '', trim($value['Input VAT per client']))),
```

Comment: That works, thanks, but you forgot `$value` in `trim(['Input VAT per client'])))`

Comment: That's okay, I get it